# Why does turtle.stamp() give me expected floating-point number but got "floating"?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Inside of the Draw function i use the stamp() function. It gives me the error from the title. I think it has something to do with the numbers being too small but why does it give me an error when stamping?

```
import turtle
import random
import numpy as np
import math
import time
Wn = turtle.Screen()
Wn.setup(1000, 550)
Wn.tracer(0)
Point = turtle.Turtle()
Point.penup()
Point.hideturtle()
Detail = 1
Chance = 1
World = np.array([0, 0, 0])
for x in range(Detail * 2):
    for y in range(Detail * 2):
        for z in range(Detail * 2):
            if random.randint(0, Chance - 1) == 0:
                Pos = np.array([(x - (Detail - 0.5)) / Detail, (y - (Detail - 0.5)) / Detail, (z - (Detail - 0.5)) / Detail])
                World = np.vstack([World, Pos])
print(World)
def zMove(World, Step):
    for P in range(len(World)):
        World[P][2] += Step
    return World
def Projection2D(World):
    Points2D = []
    for P in World:
        Distance = math.sqrt((P[0] * 0.01) ** 2 + (P[1] * 0.01) ** 2 + (P[2] - 1) ** 2)
        d = 3.25 / (Distance - P[2])
        Points2D.append([P[0] * 250 * d, P[1] * 250 * d])
    return Points2D
def Draw(World2D):
    Point.clear()
    Point.penup()
    Point.hideturtle()
    Point.shape("circle")
    Point.turtlesize(0.5)
    for pos in World2D:
        Point.goto(pos[0], pos[1])
        Point.stamp()
while True:
    # World = xRotateWorld(World, 0.01)
    # World = yRotateWorld(World, 0)
    # World = zRotateWorld(World, 0)
    zMove(World, 0.1)
    Points2D = Projection2D(World)
    Draw(Points2D)
    Wn.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

It has something to do with the zMove function. If i don't call that function it works fine.

(And as a little extra can somebody explain if there is a better way to get projection added. I think i did it in a weird way).

Comment: I ran your code and there is an issue at `d = 3.25 / (Distance - P[2])` when `Distance - P[2] = 0`. Since you can't divide by 0, you need to handle this.

Comment: I suggest a [mcve]. I don't think all of this code is necessary to reproduce the titular error. This makes the post more useful and increases the chances of someone writing an answer. Thanks.